# Edit file metadata - Code is fine in VB but not C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection, metadata

Here is the VB.NET method currently used, which works just fine.

```
Private Sub editMetadata(ByRef bmp1 As Bitmap, ByVal intTitleId As Integer, ByVal strTitle As String)

        Dim ci As System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo = _
                       GetType(PropertyItem).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or _
                       BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.[Public], Nothing, New Type() {}, Nothing)

        Dim outPropertyItem As PropertyItem = DirectCast(ci.Invoke(Nothing), PropertyItem)

        outPropertyItem.Id = intTitleId

        ' Type=1 means Array of Bytes. 
        outPropertyItem.Type = 1
        outPropertyItem.Len = strTitle.Length

        outPropertyItem.Value = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strTitle)

        bmp1.SetPropertyItem(outPropertyItem)

End Sub
```

---

---

Now in C#, I've run into a road block with the very first line of this method.

```
System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo ci = 
      GetType(PropertyItem).GetConstructor( BindingFlags.NonPublic ||
      BindingFlags.Instance || BindingFlags.[Public], null, new Type() {}, null);
```

---

---

After converting syntax from VB to C# (what I'm familiar with) I've still got 6 errors on this one section.

[image: Error]

---

---

So, the issue could be solved a couple ways...

What's the right C# syntax for the code shown above.

OR..

How do I edit the files metadata correctly in C#.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Use | instead of || in BindingFlags

Comment: Ah, that got rid of error #3.  thank you :)  !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo ci = 
      typeof(PropertyItem).GetConstructor( BindingFlags.NonPublic |
      BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] {}, null);
```

Comment: I've removed the [] around BindingFlags.Public, and then this is all correct.  Thanks!!  Will mark as answer in 10 minutes when its allowed.